# Display: None in @media is acting globally

Tags: html, css, display

I have 2 main issues that I can't figure out.

1) I have a hidden widget area that should only display when the max-width is `1338px`, and at the very same time, my right widget should disappear.

The issue is that when I add `display: none;` to hide the left widget it stays hidden even when the max-width reaches `1338px`.

In my `@media` I have it set to `display:block` for the `max-width: 1338px;`

2) The next issue I have is my left sidebar has a photo gallery that should disappear when the the `max-width` reaches `923px`

But when I add `display:none` to the `@media` for `max-width: 923px;` it displays nothing no matter what the width of the screen is. It displays nothing even if I am at a screen size above 923px in width.

Here is a link to a sample of the site I am working on. https://codepen.io/christiangutierrezreyez/pen/aMXpQd?editors=1100

The areas you may find the issues in are in the CSS in lines
169 through 192
And 351. I commented out line 352 because that line is giving me the problem.

I apologize for not cutting out the areas so it could be more readable. But I wouldn't know what sections to cut out and which sections to leave.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! And I thank you for your time.

Comment: First one works fine when I test it, both in Firefox and Chrome. Above 1338px the right bar is visible, below it the left bar is visible. And both correctly hide as well. How are you testing it and in which browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the left panel and gallery, your closing `}` for the media query was too early, and didn't envelope `#photos-left-sidebar-wrapper, #hidden-left-sidebar`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEJWop?editors=1100

Comment: I see the extra bracket now. Nice catch. I have to learn how to catch those errors myself. Been scratching my head all day. hahaha. Thank you!